# Do numeric CSS rule values in React need quotes?

Tags: css, reactjs

If I wanted to use inline styles in React return{}, do numeric values need quotes?

For example, in width: 50%;

Does 50% need to be enclosed in quotes?

If so, why?

I was shown a line of React code and asked about it. But I don't work in a React environment, so I was surprised to see the quotes.

Comment: You're not writing "CSS" in "React", you're writing Javascript. so: would `width: 50%;` be valid JS without any quotes anywhere?

Comment: `50%` isn't a numeric value. It's a string. 50% as a number is `0.50`.

Comment: Thanks for that clarifying point. I will edit my post. It was actually a case where a CSS rule was being added into a line of React code. I wish I would have copied the code. It was in a question someone asked me about, but I'm not a React developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the type of numeric value you use.

There are four types of numeric values in CSS:

- `Integer`: whole number
- `Number`: can be a decimal or a fraction
- `Dimension`: a `number` with a unit attached to it e.g. `20px`
- `Percentage`: a `number` with a `%` that represents a fraction

In Javascript, only the `integer` and `number` types are considered numeric and as such can be written without quotes in a JSX inline style object, otherwise you need to wrap your `dimension` or `percentage` in quotes because they're parsed as strings.

So if this is the CSS you want:

```
div {
   opacity: 0.6;  // number, doesn't need quotes in JS
   height: 20px;  // dimension
   width: 50%;    // percentage
}
```

Your JSX would look like this:

```
return (
  <div style={{ opacity: 0.6, height: "20px", width: "50%" }}>
    {/* Content */}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (
  <div style={{ width: '50%' }}>
    {/* Your component's content */}
  </div>
);
```

In this case, the value '50%' is a string and should be enclosed in quotes because it is a CSS value. The quotes are necessary to indicate that it is a string value representing a percentage.

```
return (
  <div style={{ width: 50 }}>
    {/* Your component's content */}
  </div>
);
```

In this case, 50 is interpreted as a numeric value and not a string.